# Gulp3 to gulp 4 upgrade. Function with condition

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gulp

Could you please help me with my problem?
I'm trying to upgrade my gulpfile from 3 to 4 version.
And I have this code

```
gulp.task('test', production() ? ['test2'] : null, function () {
// do something
});

gulp.task('test 2',  function () {
// do something
});

gulp.task('test4', gulp.series('test', 'test5'), function () {
// do something
});
```

And i have error - task test never defined.
If i remove production() ? ['test2'] : null everything works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gulp.task`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task#parameters) expects only one argument for tasks, it should be not an array but `gulp.series` or `gulp.parallel` for composed task - which is already used in another task.

It can be:

```
gulp.task('test', gulp.series(...[
  production() && 'test2',
  function () { ... }
].filter(Boolean)));
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is equals with my initial code?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure. Tasks from the array run in parallel https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#deps in Gulp 3 but since you have the only `task2` as a dep, there's no difference.